# NPM package installed without saving are getting removed when new package is being installed

Tags: node.js, express, npm, package

I have a project in Express.js where I need to install new packages, to add new features. However, when I am installing new packages, some of the old packages (probably which weren't installed with save command), are getting uninstalled. Is there a way, package.json can be updated by reading package-lock.json dependencies, so new dependencies do not remove older ones?

Suggestions would be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a small list of packages removing other packages?

Comment: One of the package, I am trying to install is multer-s3

Comment: Delete your node modules folder once & npm install once.

Comment: I managed to get away with the situation by not saving my new dependencies either (perhaps a temp. solution).

Answer (score 1):

**Update npm 5:**

As of npm 5.0.0, installed modules are added as a dependency by default, so the --save option is no longer needed. The other save options still exist and are listed in the documentation for npm install.

**Before NPM 5:**

Before version 5, NPM simply installed a package under node_modules by default. When you were trying to install dependencies for your app/module, you would need to first install them, and then add them (along with the appropriate version number) to the dependencies section of your package.json.

The --save option instructed NPM to include the package inside of the dependencies section of your package.json automatically, thus saving you an additional step.

In addition, there are the complementary options --save-dev and --save-optional which save the package under devDependencies and optionalDependencies, respectively. This is useful when installing development-only packages, like grunt or your testing library.

Comment: So the dependencies are not added to package.json, which is causing trouble for new packages, is there way to manage this?